# Android Studio: Youtube notification titles/text

Tags: java, android

I have a program that gets a notification's title and text through the NotificationListenerService. It currently works for everything but Youtube notifications. I am getting the text and titles through this:
`notification.extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT);`

However, Youtube's text/title is null. The Youtube notification clearly has a title and text, but none of the Extra keys seem to work.

On the other hand, other notifications return both the title and text.

I am expecting the title and text in the youtube notification to be returned, which is something along the lines of: Title: Youtuber posted a video! Text: Watch now!. Any idea how I would get the text and title of the notification?

Comment: Could you please provide more a technical explanation? Are you using NotificationListenerService? What fields are you expecting and why?

Comment: Hi, I am using NotificationListenerService. I am expecting the title and text in the youtube notification to be returned, which is something along the lines of: Title: Youtuber posted a video! Text: Watch now!